# Javascript button onclick not working on Mobile browser

Tags: javascript

Button onclick using mobile browser does not work. It works fine on laptop browser.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="button1" style="margin:5px" onClick="myupdate()">Check Services</button>

function myupdate(event) {
        socket.emit("my_event", function(msg) {
       });
}
```

Comment: Where/how is socket defined?

Comment: I am using FastAPI with socketIO. Does socket would really matter here ?

Comment: it absolutely does because unless you provide proof that the event isn't firing, we must assume there's a possibility that socket.emit is the thing that's actually failing.    Replace it with an alert and see if you get the alert to appear.

Comment: The socket emit and associated function does work as it is working on laptop/desktop browser. So I believe it is more related to Javascript event not working ONLY on mobile ??

Comment: @Chandan What if the socket doesn't work on mobile?

Comment: So, I checked and what it appears that socket emit is not working for mobile click event. I tested with Javascript alert without emit and it displays using mobile button click. So it seems like mobile browser is not able to send the click event to server.

Comment: @Zachiah ,  so the issue was with mobile which was did not opened a socket connection with server. I could verify this with the  on "connect" event logs. Hence the click event could not be detected.